# Search for characters within a string with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search

Let's say, for example, that you have a random string in the DB: **APKHDP**

I want to search all strings that contain the characters PHP (in that order). So I search for PHP and it returns the above string. Or I search for HPP, and it returns nothing.

Is there a simple solution to make this possible, perhaps using REGEX? It sounds very simple. But the asnwers I am finding are massively complex so far.

I am using this with PHP (hence the example!), and I'm happy to integrate PHP into the solution if it's the best way forward.

Comment: Can you not just use a like select? Maybe I'm missing something:
select * from myTable where myField like '%PHP%'

Comment: As far as  i got it, this is not a PHP-related question. If you have random field-contents and you want to show only rows that match a particular string, use:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE "%PHP%";

Comment: It seems that LIKE is no good for the question, because they want to match a pattern, rather than a fixed string or partial string.

Comment: Thanks Codecraft, yes LIKE is no good for me as it wouldn't match the above example string. Unless there is another way of using it, which I don't know about? I need to match the characters, in order - not just the string itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text_field REGEXP '.*P.*H.*P.*'
```

The [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html).

Comment: xdazz, you're a star. Thank you very much. Just went through the format with my REGEX cheatsheet and it makes perfect sense now. Nice and simple too. Just what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use a MySQL regular expression - you can match things, but can't replace - for example:

SELECT 'APKHDP' REGEXP('[PHP]')

Returns '1' (ie, the regexp matched the string).

Although the regular expression above may not be correct for your needs (it matches any use of the letters P, H and P) so you'd have to tweak that.

You could make your regex more complicated, or you could do multiple matches:

```
SELECT field FROM TABLE WHERE field REGEXP(match1) AND field REGEXP(match2)..etc
```

Whichever seems simplest to you...

Link: [MySQL Manual for REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Comment: I was thinking along these lines initially. And I guess it would work, albeit a little messy. Appreciate the response though. Any solution is better than no solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `COLUMNS` 
WHERE  `TABLE_NAME` 
REGEXP  'APKHDP'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this returns the exact string. As with LIKE.